# What userAgent do I need for the method to return true?

Tags: java, jsoup, user-agent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbjn9.png)

I wanted to make a parsing program for one popular site, but it has protection. I also heard that the site has group ib and ja3.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fBdc.png)I've been trying to bypass this check in Java, so far it's not working out so well.

```html
function browser_is_IE11() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
  var rv = -1;

  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
    // If Internet Explorer, return version number
    if (isNaN(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))))) {
      //For IE 11 >
      if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null) {
          rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
          if (rv == 11) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your code is text. Please share it as such, not as pictures.

Comment: Added the code in text format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Example of useragent to return `true` from this method:

```
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE ; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/7.0rv:11.0)")
```